# Why do we need to do work to maintain motion of a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy, flow, bernoulli-equation, viscosity

On page 355 of principles of physics by Resnick walker and Halliday, the author writes:

> Work must also be done on the system (at the input end) to push the entering fluid into the tube and by the system (at the output end) to push forward the fluid that is located ahead of the emerging fluid. In general , the work done by a force of magnitude $\textit{F}$, acting on a fluid sample contained in a tube of area $\textit{A}$ to move the fluid through a distance $\Delta x$, is
> $$ F \Delta x = pA \Delta x = p(A \Delta x) = p \Delta V $$

According to newton's first law, an object in motion remains in motion unless acted by an unbalanced external force .So, if we take the bulk of fluid as an object, then it would continue motion unless forces act on it. Then why is that we always have a pressure difference at ends of the tube that we take? As in, the paragraph I quoted suggests that we need to do some work to push fluid whether stationary or moving over a displacement.

As a side note, I recall in thermodynamics that we do $ \int P dV$ to attain work, however this is an expansion work. So, would a correct interpretation of the formula be that work is done for expanding the fluids volume? Precisely speaking, as the fluid flows, it is expanding it's own volume (in a way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Work must also be done on the system (at the input end) to push the
> entering fluid into the tube and by the system (at the output end) to
> push forward the fluid that is located ahead of the emerging fluid.

This pressure can be estimated, *or at least understood*, by means of the Bernoulli Principle (so for an ideal, inviscid fluid).

[image: Bernoulli]

$$p_1+\frac12 \rho v_1^2+\rho gz_1=p_2+\frac12 \rho v_2^2+\rho gz_2$$

Assume $v_1\approx 0$ (or at least $v_2 \gg v_1$) and the potential energy changes negligible, then the above equation reduces to:

$$\Delta p\approx -\frac12 \rho v_2^2$$

where $v_2$ is calculated from the volumetric flow rate. $\Delta p$ is negative because it is a pressure *drop*.

So $\Delta p$ is required to impart kinetic energy to the fluid by the pump to keep fluid entering the pipe.

---

> As a side note, I recall in thermodynamics that we do ∫PdV to attain
> work, however this is an expansion work. So, would a correct
> interpretation of the formula be that work is done for expanding the
> fluids volume?

The fluid is considered incompressible ($\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}=0$) so there's no compression or expansion going on ($\Delta V=0$)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: question: here is a law of fluid dynamics that I thought of, " A fluid maintains it's motion in lack of presence of external pressures ?" do you think this would be valid?

Comment: Yes but the problem is that although fluid may be incompressible and inviscid, it's still very sensitive to deformation by gravity. A fluid running through a pipe would quickly 'smear out' due to gravity... So your Law is very much 'on paper only'...

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but here is my response. I will delete if it's not on-topic.

Assume no losses due to friction. Then note that every small volume of fluid that we wish to push into the pipe must be given a certain flow velocity, after which that fluid element will coast its way down the length of the pipe with that velocity, and leave the end of the pipe with that velocity.

Therefore, the pump at the head end of the pipe is continuously performing work on the fluid it is pushing into the pipe, to accelerate it up from zero to the flow velocity of the rest of the fluid in the pipe. That acceleration work is present even if there is no viscuous dissipation occurring inside the pipe.

Comment: Unclear in what sense?

Hm, this answer contradicts what Gert has said. However, then a question arises, if the pressure work accelerates the fluid, what if the fluid was already moving with some velocity, then would pressure be 0? As in does existence of pressure implictly accelerate fluids

Comment: No, it doesn't 'contradict' what I wrote but @NN and me seem to be answering different questions. NN did understands the question correctly IMHO. +1.from me.

Comment: The pressure difference $\Delta p$ at the entrance can in fact be estimated with Bernouilli.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ultimately due to viscosity. Viscosity serves as an energy "sink" – it constantly dissipates energy out of the system. Viscosity is due to the friction between two layers of fluids moving at different speeds and hence "dragging" each other. With ideal fluids (ones with no viscosity), kinetic energy is conserved, assuming no external forces.

The mathematical justification for this is a little involved, but I'll leave it here for anyone who's interested. Consider the Navier-Stokes equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u}=-\nabla(p / \rho)+v \nabla^{2} \mathbf{u}.
\end{equation}
Dot both sides of this equation with the field velocity $\mathbf{u}$. With some manipulation, this is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^{2}\right]=-\nabla \cdot\left[\left(\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^{2}+p / \rho\right) \mathbf{u}\right]+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[\tau_{i j} u_{i} / \rho\right]-2 v S_{i j} S_{i j}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tau_{i j}=\rho \nu\left(\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}+\frac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_{j}}\right) = 2 \rho \nu S_{ij}.
\end{equation}
Take the integral of both sides so that we get the time rate of change of the total kinetic energy in the system on the LHS. Using the divergence theorem, and the assumption that $\mathbf{u}$ dies off either at some boundary or at infinity, we are left with:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^{2} \mathrm{d} V=-\int 2 \nu S_{i j} S_{i j} \mathrm{d} V\equiv-\int \varepsilon \mathrm{d} V
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon = 2 \nu S_{ij} S_{ij} \geq 0$. Thus, kinetic energy is continuously being lost out due to viscosity, and work is needed to keep a fluid moving.

Comment: I understand the viscosity is sort of like friction for fluids, but  in an ideal fluid is viscosity conditions even considered?

Comment: The quotation is about an ideal, inviscid fluid.

Comment: I mean, yes, but you bring aspect of viscosity to explain my question in which the author says that we are neglecting viscosity

Comment: I understand, but my point was to show that the loss in kinetic energy is (typically) *solely* due to viscosity. As I mention in the answer, no work is needed to maintain the kinetic energy of an ideal fluid. If you set $\nu = 0$ in the derivation I mentioned, you will find that total dissipation $\varepsilon$ is zero.